# Margins not clickable: Box Model confusion

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make an entire table cell clickable. The general advice I have found is to use `display: block;` but all of the examples I have seen have only a single line cells. I have cells with rowspans that seem to make life harder.

Consider this brightly coloured example:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style type="text/css">
            td { border: 1px; background-color: blue; }
            td a { display: block; background-color: yellow; border: 1px solid red; }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td rowspan=2><a href="#">Left</a></td>
                <td><a href="#">Upper Right</a></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><a href="#">Lower Right</a></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

The anchor tag's block (yellow) is all clickable. But the left hand side has (blue) margins above and below it that are not clickable. I guess I need something to increase the padding to fill the full td cell on the left (without changing the size of the cells on the right), but I haven't been able to find the right incantation to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
td a {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: yellow;
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

***[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mattball/ChFDn/)***

[image: example]

Comment: Ah, I experimented with inline-block, and I experimented with height: 100%, but I never tried BOTH at the same time. Thank you!

Comment: To give an inline element height, you need to use `display: inline-block;`

Comment: Works in Chrome, but not in Firefox 3.6.16. :-( [I don't care about IE or Safari on this project.]

Comment: Eventually the problem went away with other edits. I never found nailed this down 100%, but this was helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Another option would be to use a javascript package like jquery or YUI and add a click listener to the `<td>` rather than just the `<a>`